# Dart: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String?>' in Mockito

Tags: dart, mockito

The code below used to work before null safety, but now I get "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String?>'" and I have absolutely no idea why and what to do. Please help, this should be really easy (except for me), because you just have to copy the code and run it as test to get the exception:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockMethodChannel extends Mock implements MethodChannel {}

void main() {

  group('all', () {

      test('test', () async {
        final mockMethodChannel = MockMethodChannel();
        when(mockMethodChannel
            .invokeMethod<String>("GET com.eight/preference-management/preferences"))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => "test");
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Wehn null safety was added to mockito, the mocking of classes was changed, take a look at this, Ive been struggling with it for a bit: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/403 and also you can look at the documentation: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md, Its been a little rought to make the switch, let me know if you need further help buddy.

Comment: That works fine, thank's a lot! Just added the following and everything is fine:


`
import 'preference_datasource_test.mocks.dart';



@GenerateMocks([], customMocks: [MockSpec<MethodChannel>(as: #MockMethodChannel)])
`

Comment: Great!! Im glad you managed to fix that !

Comment: Any chance you can upvote my comment ?

Answer (score 20):

Your signature for `MethodChannel.invokeMethod` function says it returns a `Future<String?>` but since the `MockMethodChannel` doesnot have any implementation for `invokeMethod()` , it will return `null`; dart's null safety gets angry because you lied. For a quick fix, the `invokeMethod` can have a return type of `Future<String?>?`. When you do so, you are saying null safety shouldn't bother even if the returned value is null.

However this is not a permanent solution I just want you to understand the problem.

you could add build_runner in your dev_dependencies: in pubspec.yaml

`dart pub add build_runner --dev`

and modify your code to

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
//modified
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'generated file.dart';

class MockMethodChannel extends Mock implements MethodChannel {}

//modified
@GenerateMocks([MockMethodChannel])
void main() {

  group('all', () {

      test('test', () async {
        final mockMethodChannel = MockMockMethodChannel();
        when(mockMethodChannel
            .invokeMethod<String>("GET com.eight/preference-management/preferences"))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => "test");
      });
  });
}
```

and run
`flutter pub run  build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` for build runner to build the stub files for you

Comment: one should add real MethodChannel class name within the GenerateMocks param list so that it can be generated as expected
```
@GenerateMocks([MockMethodChannel])
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Flutter with null safety, then the way to create a mock class is different, you need to use `@GenerateMocks` annotation now.

Please read [documentation on null safety](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md).

Answer (score 4):

**if you want a simple way just do like this**

```
   class WorkerAPI {
         late ApiHelper _helper;
        
          WorkerAPI() {
            _helper = GetIt.I<ApiHelper>();
          }
        
          Future<Result<List<WorkerModel>>> getWorkers() async {
            return await _helper.get(
                url: urls.workers,
                onSuccess: (response) {
                  Iterable listJson = json.decode(response.body);
                  List<WorkerModel> list =
                      listJson.map((e) => WorkerModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
                  return list;
                });
          }
    
     // override your method in mock with Non-nullable return type
    
      class WorkerApiMock extends Mock implements WorkerAPI {
          @override
          Future<Result<List<WorkerModel>>> getWorkers() {
             return super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#getWorkers,null),
             returnValue:Future.value(Result.success(List.filled(0,WorkerModel()))));
        }
    
    }
```

if you want check this => https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/test/manual_mocks_test.dart

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue, and it was just because I moved my test class from one directory to another.

So I deleted my `.mocks.dart` file, regenerated it using `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`, and my test was working again.