# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast in flutter - 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter

For the shopping cart section, the store app and the product list view show this error The error I mentioned in the title

**These are the shopping cart codes:**

```
*// ignore_for_file: file_names
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Cart{
  static Future<bool> add_product_cart(String product_id, String title, int price, String img_url) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //prefs.remove('products_id');
    final products_id = prefs.getString("products_id");
    if(products_id != null){
      if(products_id.indexOf(product_id) >= 0){
        await change_number_product(product_id);
      }else{
        //print("new product");
        String data = products_id + product_id + "_";
        prefs.setString('products_id', data);
        await add_product_data(product_id, title, price, img_url);
      }
    }else{
      //print("add_product_data1");
      String data = product_id + "_";
      prefs.setString('products_id', data);
      await add_product_data(product_id, title, price, img_url);
    }
    return true; 
  }
  static add_product_data(String product_id,String title,int price,String img_url)async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //print("add_product_data method");
    prefs.setString('title_'+product_id, title);
    prefs.setInt('price_'+product_id, price);
    prefs.setString('img_url'+product_id, img_url);
    prefs.setInt('number_'+product_id, 1);
  }
  static change_number_product(String product_id) async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //("change_number_product method");
    int n = prefs.getInt('number_' + product_id)!.toInt();
    n = n + 1;
    prefs.setInt('number_' + product_id, n);
    
  }
  static Future<bool> remove_cart_product(String product_id) async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //print("remove_cart_product method");
    String products_id = prefs.getString("products_id").toString();
    products_id = products_id.replaceAll(product_id + "_", "");
     if (products_id.isEmpty){
       prefs.remove('products_id');
     }else{
       prefs.setString('products_id' , products_id);
     }
     prefs.remove('title_'+product_id);
     prefs.remove('price_'+product_id);
     prefs.remove('img_url_'+product_id);
     prefs.remove('number_'+product_id);
     return true;
  }
  static Future<bool> empty_cart() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String products_id = prefs.getString("products_id").toString();
    List<String> products_Id = products_id.split('_');
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (products_id.length -1); i++){
      prefs.remove('title_'+products_Id[i]);
      prefs.remove('price_'+products_Id[i]);
      prefs.remove('img_url_'+products_Id[i]);
      prefs.remove('number_'+products_Id[i]);
    }
    prefs.remove("products_id");
    return true;
  }
  static Future<String> get_cart_product() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String products_id = prefs.getString("products_id").toString();
    return products_id;
  }
  static Future<Map<String,dynamic>> get_product_data(String product_id) async{
    Map<String,dynamic> data = Map();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String title = prefs.getString('title_' + product_id).toString();
    int price = prefs.getInt('price_' + product_id) ?? 0;
    String img_url = prefs.getString('img_url_' + product_id).toString();
    int number = prefs.getInt('number_' + product_id) ?? 0;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['price'] = price;
    data['img_url'] = img_url;
    data['number'] = number;
    //print("get_product_data");
    return data;
  }
}*
```

**The following _CastError was thrown resolving an image codec:**
ERROR: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool', stack trace: #0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String?>' in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371802/dart-type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futurestring-in-mockito)

Comment: all Null questions are similar. If you instance of object wasn't created then, it's Null. I recommend you to read: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

in the below, you don't check for null.  Same for empty_cart.  Check for null.

```
String products_id = prefs.getString("products_id").toString();
products_id = products_id.replaceAll(product_id + "_", "");
```

Comment: " It may sound strange, but I changed part of the above code as below and the problem was fixed
I put it here, it might be useful for another user
Thankful " ---->

 String? title = prefs.getString('title_' + product_id).toString();
    int? price = prefs.getInt('price_' + product_id) as int?;
    String? img_url = prefs.getString('img_url_' + product_id).toString();
    int? number = prefs.getInt('number_' + product_id) as int?;

Comment: You explicitly made them nullable, as opposed to the assumed non-nullable without the ?. You'll still need to check for null for your products_id before you can replaceAll.  I suggest migrating to null safety to allow the ide to help you with these things.